# phrase meaning "to progress through an outlined set of steps/time"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

How do you refer to a person continuing along an outlined path through time? Specifically, what do you call the actual action of progressing from the earlier stages to the later/older stages?

I'm trying refer to the path a person takes through college (year 1, then 2, then 3, etc.), and what you would call the act of going through those steps/ progressing to the later ones.

The sentence I'm trying to complete is "it is common for students to do this as they _____." It needs to mean something like "progress through their years at school" or "get older", but "older/aging" only in reference to them rising through the grades. I just don't know how to say that in a shorter, more concise manner instead of literally stating "progress through their time at school".
I know there has to be some better phrase that means "the act of someone moving through this specifically outlined set of time".

Comment: Why not simply *progress*?

Comment: "progress" would work but only in a more lengthy description, like to literally say "they progress through the years of being at school", but I'm looking more for like a shorter idiom or phrase that implies that same meaning.

Comment: Since you have established some context with the word *students*, the phrase *as they progress* is sufficient to imply *through their education*.

Answer (score 2):

The word "advance" is currently used in this way.

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/advance) offers this definition, marked 1.1:

> advance : Make or cause to make progress

An example sentence: "Michael advanced from third to fourth grade."

When progression is marked by a series of steps, this is the most common word used to describe progression through the steps in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

They go/progress through their **rites of passage** (the broader sense given by [Collins](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rite-of-passage) ):

> *rite of passage* noun
>
> 1.a ceremony performed in some cultures at times when an individual changes his status, as at puberty and marriage
>
> 2.a significant event in a transitional period of someone's life

Answer (score 0):

Although the wording is no shorter than that of "progress through their years at school," "**continue [or *progress* or *advance*] along their academic path**" offers a fairly relaxed, figurative way of describing what you refer to in your question title "progressing through an outlined set of steps/time."

Answer (score 0):

The formal set of experiences necessary to fulfill the requirements of a degree or certification is often known as a [curriculum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curriculum).  Sounds like you want some variation of an broader idiom which connotes either adherence, accordance, or lack thereof, to the requirements stipulated.

- **[on track](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+track)**
  “That person is *on track* to complete their degree — in ten years!”
- **[on the way](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+way)**
  “I'm well *on my way* to an early graduation.”
  **Note**:  do not confuse this with similar idioms such as ‘[along the way](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/along+the+way)’ or ‘[by the way](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+the+way)’.

Well, I suppose I shall leave it at that for this answer.